# how to stop sortable event with cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `draggable` list, and a `sortable` list. The `draggable` list will have ALL possible items. The `sortable` list is the user's selections.

I want the `sortable` to do a check on `receive` to see if the item already exists, and if so, stop the sort and `revert` the item back to the draggable list. However, even when the `cancel` event fires, the `update` event continues and the revert never happens.

What am I missing?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XW48M/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <ul id="teams" class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item poll-assets" data-id="1" data-name="Team 1">Team 1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item poll-assets" data-id="2" data-name="Team 2">Team 2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item poll-assets" data-id="3" data-name="Team 3">Team 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <ul id="poll" class="list-group">
                <li id="1" class="list-group-item poll-item" data-id="1" data-name="Team 1">Team 1</li>
                <li id="4" class="list-group-item poll-item" data-id="4" data-name="Team 4">Team 4</li>
                <li id="5" class="list-group-item poll-item" data-id="5" data-name="Team 5">Team 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#poll").sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function (event, ui) {
            console.log('update');
            var order = $("#poll").sortable("toArray");
            if ($(ui.item).hasClass('ui-draggable')) {
                $(ui.item).addClass('poll-item').removeClass('ui-draggable draggable').attr('id', $(ui.item).data('id'));
            }
        },
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            console.log('receive');
            var order = $( "#poll" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var id = $(ui.item.data('id'));
                if ($.inArray(id, order)) {
                $("#poll").sortable('cancel');
                console.log('CANCELLED');
                return;
            } else {
                $(ui.item).remove();
            }
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    $('#teams')
        .find('.poll-assets').draggable({
        opacity: 0.75,
        appendTo: document.body,
        helper: 'clone',
        connectToSortable: '#poll',
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Please post your code here so that it will be preserved for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="leftDiv">
    <div class="item item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item item2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item item3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item item4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item item5">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item item6">Item 6</div>
</div>
<div class="rightDiv">

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".leftDiv .item").draggable({
        helper: function(ev, ui) {
            return "<span class='helperPick'>"+$(this).html()+"</span>";
        },
        connectToSortable: ".rightDiv"
    });

    $(".rightDiv").sortable({
        'items': ".item",
        'receive': function(event, ui){
            // find the class of the dropped ui, look for the one with the integer suffix.
            var clazz = getClassNameWithNumberSuffix(ui.item);
            $('.leftDiv .' + clazz).draggable( "option", "revert", true )
            if($('.rightDiv .' + clazz).length > 1){
                $('.rightDiv .' + clazz + ':not(:first)').remove();                
            }
        }
    });

});

function getClassNameWithNumberSuffix(el) {
  var className = null;
  var regexp = /\w+\d+/;
  $($(el).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() {
    if (regexp.test(this)) {
      className = this;
      return false;
    }
  });

  return className;
}
```

CSS:

```
.leftDiv, .rightDiv {width:120px; float:left; border:1px solid #000; padding:5px; margin:10px; min-height:130px}
.rightDiv {margin-left:40px}

.item {height:20px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #EEE; background-color:#FFF}

.helperPick {border:1px dashed red; height:20px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; width:120px}
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/perrytew/RxKkA/3/

Comment: @xgreen-- I'm not sure why you assumed I didn't do any research-- I posted a nearly working prototype, which was one of about 6-7 I built unsuccessfully to try to get this working as I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you went with draggable + sortable instead of 2 connected sortables.

So i gave it a try using this method and i came with something like that :

```
$("#teams").sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith: "#poll",
    start: function () {
        console.log('start');
        var order = $('#poll').sortable("toArray", {
            attribute: "data-id"
        });
        $('#poll').data('order', order);
    }
}).disableSelection();


$("#poll").sortable({
    revert: true,
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('receive');
        var order = $('#poll').data('order');
        var id = $(ui.item).data('id').toString();
        if ($.inArray(id, order) != -1) {
            console.log('CANCELLED');
            $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
        } else {
            console.log('NOT CANCELLED');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Main issue was to get the correct item array, because on receive event, the array is already updated with the "newly" added item. I had to put it inside data on the start event of the other sortable and to get it back on receive event.

I still find a few things not very satisfying:

- Using id selectors inside start and receive callbacks; but event arguments didn't contain the elements i needed
- The revert effect is quite ... weird

Anyhow, it is the closest i could get to what you expected; i also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/fBbwj/1/) for you to check.

Let me know if it helps / post your code if you can get anything better.

Comment: @Florian-- thanks. I had been using two sortables, but the original list shouldn't be sortable-- just draggable. I guess it's not a huge difference in usability, though it could be confusing. If it makes more sense to use two sortables and that works better, I"m ok with that.